# Flex Advanced data grid:column visibility

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

HI
I am new to Flex and was wondering, when we use an advanced data grid, only when we click on the parent element the children details get populated in the corresponding columns, right?..SO now i have made the empty columns invisible(at design) now how do i make them visible at run time **when the parent element is expanded**..similarly once the columns are visible, how can i make them invisible again when the parent element is closed.
Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at using a Tree instead of a grid. The idiom of a grid is a ledger book; the columns do not change.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the event you want to listen for is "itemOpen" then the function you want will be something like:

MyADG.columns[invisible column index].visible=true;